# JavaFX project won't to Clean and Build

Tags: java, javafx, build

I have a JavaFx project that was compiling just fine.

Now, it won't "*Clean and Build*", and instead I get `No available classes`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just renaming the project made it work:

`Project -> Properties -> Application -> Title`